# TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'

Tags: angularjs

I have searched other solutions but it doesn't work, solution was to put isArray: true, but it doent work. I am working with objects btw. I am getting this message in console, but everything works, data has been send to my backend api. How to remove that error ?

```
app.factory('Category', function($resource, $http) {
return $resource('http://localhost/api/v1/category/', {id: "@id"},
    {
        update: {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: false
        },
        save: {
            method: 'PUT'
        },
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            params: {id: '@id'},
            isArray: false
        },
        create: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
        },
        drop: {
            method: 'DELETE',
            params: {id: '@id'}
        }
    }
);
});
```

Here is my function

```
    $scope.createInventory = function(){
        Inventory.create($scope.newinfo);
        $scope.info.push(Inventory);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $scope.info not a array. You must specify $scope.info to array, then you can push any values to $scope.info.

Try this

```
  $scope.info=[];
  $scope.createInventory = function(){
        Inventory.create($scope.newinfo);            
        $scope.info.push(Inventory);
    };
```

Comment: that worked, tnx. Quick question. Should data automatically show up when displaying them, if i am dealing with objects? With strings using push they automatically show up, is there any solution?

Comment: You need to use [ng-repeat](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) for bind the values to html controls

Comment: I am doing like this `<tr ng-repeat="inventory in info.objects">` and then `{{inventory.name}}` or should i bind other way? It shows data just after reloading the page